# Ext JS 4 - how to add a time stamp to a text area form field?

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, events, extjs, textarea

I have an form with a text area field.  I want to add some text (a date/time stamp) when the user clicks in to the form.  I am assuming I need to catch a click type event when the user clicks in to the field and then edit the field value and insert the text I want.   Is this the best approach?

Looking for suggestions based on using Ext JS 4 / MVC.

Comment: Why would you add a timestamp directly to the text? Are you saving this in a database? Do you want to know the exact time the user focuses the field?

Comment: I guess it does not have to be that exact, but the idea is when they click in, it adds something like  "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm username - " and hopefully then move the insertion point after the dash so they start typing.   I know I could handle these notes as separate database records, just not sure I want to go that direction yet.

Comment: If you're going to store it in a db, I can't imagine you'd rather parse the data out of a text node than just reference the record directly. That said, while the outcome sounds wrong, your approach sounds correct. Listen for the "focus" event, update the contents, move the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by you - "I need to catch a click type event when the user clicks in to the field" - One way to achieve this and appending of timestamp to the value could be by using the focus event in following manner:

```
focus:function(){
    var value       =       this.getValue();
    value           +=      new Date().getTime();
    this.setValue(value);
}
```

Just that the date used here is the client's system date.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.    I used a selector in my controllers init / me.control block:  'encounteredit textareafield': { your code here } , so my controller handles the event.